# javascript function doesn't work with two seperate pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this little code that should display a simple hello message from a page to page in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application :

In index.cshtml

```
<a href="@Url.Action("About","Home")" id="clicked_link">Click here</a>
```

In _Layout.cshtml

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(
    $("#clicked_link").click(function () {
        var url = '@Url.Action("FirstAjax","Ajax")';
        $.ajax({ url: url, success: setTimeout(function() {
            $("#result").val("Hello");
        }, 3000), type: 'POST', dataType: 'json', data: "Hello" });
    }));
</script>
```

In About.cshtml

```
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```

I need my link that will trigger the function in my Index.html page and the textarea that will contain the result in my About.cshtml page. I have put the javascript in the _Layout.csthml in order to have the possibility to have a script that interacts with the two pages. The script works fine when I put the link and the textarea wich contains the result in the same page. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: The browser only loads one page at a time.  That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I see... but is there any way to trigger a function via javascript, and then get the result of the query later in an other page ?

Comment: You need to store it somewhere permanent (cookies, local storage, server-side session).

Comment: One last question, if I trigger an action in a controller using $.ajax keyword and then move to other page, does the execution of the method in the controller is interrupted ? In other words, does page reloading stops also the Json actions that we call in the AJAX controller ?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't carry over from one page to the next. When the page change happens, any active events or scripts are stopped.

You can use the click event to add parameters to the URL before the page change happens, so you can check for them on the new page, or you use the referrer if you need this action to happen when you move from one specific page to another, but you cannot execute JavaScript across page loads.

Comment: I see, excuse my lack of knowledge for javascript and client side languages, but I have one last question, if I trigger an action in a controller using $.ajax keyword and then move to other page, does the execution of the method in the controller is interrupted ? In other words, does page reloading stops also the Json actions that we call in the AJAX controller ?

Comment: Yes. A page load stops all JavaScript. If the `$.ajax()` request causes the server to perform an action (update a profile, remove an item from the cart, etc), that will still happen, but the client does not wait for a response and no callback is executed.

Comment: That's the point ;) I just wanted to have this information, now that an action is executed on server side, the client can be notified by the end of the execution (thanks signalR). On the other hand, the client still can see the result of the execution once he returns the view cuz I can store the result in a session ;) Thank you for your reply, you just gave me the idea of the work around that I searched for days !!